# Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, hibernate

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.15.jar:8.0.15]
>
> 2019-04-25 16:29:48.930  WARN 18226 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
>   org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   2019-04-25 16:29:50.140 ERROR 18226 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run fai

I used spring boot and I still have this problem

> SpringBootApplication
>   @EnableJpaRepositories
>   public class GestionFactureApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(GestionFactureApplication.class, args);

    FactureRepository factureRepository = ctx.getBean(FactureRepository.class);

        factureRepository.save(new Facture("123",56,6,"inProgress"));
        factureRepository.save(new Facture("124",56,6,"Payed"));
        factureRepository.save(new Facture("125",56,6,"Saved"));

        RoleRepository roleRepository = ctx.getBean(RoleRepository.class);

        Role roleUser = new Role(RoleEnum.ROLE_USER);
        Role roleAdmin = new Role(RoleEnum.ROLE_ADMIN);

        roleRepository.save(roleUser);
        roleRepository.save(roleAdmin);

        UserRepository userRepository = ctx.getBean(UserRepository.class);

        User user = new User("user", "root", true);
        user.setRoles(Arrays.asList(roleUser));

        userRepository.save(user);

        User admin = new User("admin", "root", true);
        admin.setRoles(Arrays.asList(roleUser, roleAdmin));

        userRepository.save(admin);

    }
}
```

> application.properties
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/GestionFacture
>   spring.datasource.username=root spring.datasource.password=password
>   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
>
> ERROR IN PHPMYADMIN
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   La connexion au controluser tel que défini dans votre configuration a échoué.